# Worklight - Log specification doesn't match currently registered.

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

we are adding the below log level in server.xml and we are getting the below message on worllight logs can you please help us understand what will be the cause for this, (  )

```
<logging traceSpecification="*=audit=enabled:com.worklight.*=info=enabled"  traceFileName="trace.log" maxFileSize="20"  maxFiles="20" traceFormat="BASIC" />

The configured trace state included the following specifications that do not match any loggers currently registered in the server: com.worklight.*=info
com.ibm.ws.config.internal.xml.XMLBundleProcessor: The server configuration was successfully updated in 0.252 seconds
```

Thanks
djrecker

Comment: See here for something similar: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI20363

Comment: Are you specifying -javaagent ?

Answer (score 0):

That message is just a warning. We can't guarantee that all services you might conceivably trace will be ready when we parse that specification, but we try to warn you if we didn't find a match just in case you fat-fingered the string (which we know is all too easy to do).